# ASP.NET MVC Disable mobile page version?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I removed mobile CSS styles from responsive site.css file but page still loads a mobile version on mobile devices. I want my page to load on mobile devices the same way its loaded on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the head of site.css and ensure that it does not have a media tag. The default MVC4 site has a max-width constraint that affects which style sheets are used when (see the [MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs11trainingcourse_aspnetmvc4_topic2.aspx)).

You're looking for a line like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 850px) {
```